# Pandas dataframe returns key Error with all search functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Here is my python code that is not working:

```
import os, fnmatch
from openpyxl import Workbook as wb
import openpyxl as opxl
import pandas as pd

def read_excel_sheets(xls_path):
    """Read all sheets of an Excel workbook and return a single DataFrame (or in my case dictionary)"""
    print(f'Loading {xls_path} into pandas')
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(xls_path)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    columns = None    
    for idx, shtnm in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):
        print(f'Reading sheet #{idx}: {shtnm}')
        sheet = xl.parse(shtnm)
        print("You are seeing the function read_excel_sheets executing.The current sheet name is:\n",shtnm,"\n",type(shtnm))
        print("You are seeing the function read_excel_sheets executing.\n",sheet,"\n",type(sheet))
        if shtnm == 'Cover Page':
            myloc=sheet[1].str.contains('Location').any() #this line does not work
            print("first column of sheet\n",sheet[1])  
    return True
```

I do have the code going into the particular spreadsheet named 'Cover Page' but none of the search functions seem to be working (or atleast returning the desired results). I keep getting this error for the line pointed out. The return value is set to True to keep it really simple here. I have tried find(),findall(), contains(), search() but they all seem to be related to (or working with) pandas series and not necessarily with dataframes.

```
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_all_folders_files.py", line 66, in <module>
    xlparseop=read_excel_sheets(filename)
  File "read_all_folders_files.py", line 39, in read_excel_sheets
    print("first column of sheet\n",sheet[1])
  File "/Users//anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users//anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
      return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 1
```

Comment: Your KeyError is very likely happening where you declare `sheet[1]` pandas `parse()` returns: **parsed : DataFrame or Dict of DataFrames

DataFrame from the passed in Excel file. See notes in sheetname argument for more information on when a Dict of Dataframes is returned.**... In this instance you are likely calling 1 as the key of a dictionary like object...print out `type(sheet)`to see and also ensure you have that value in the object you are trying to gather

Comment: sheet is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: yes, so your error is occuring because `sheet[1]` is  not valid because the key `1` is not valid. This is why you get `KeyError: 1`. Figure out the valid key you need and you are done. Try `print(sheet.__dict__)` and you should see the attributes.